# Inner ajax getting incremented variable from for loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 ajax request one inside the other. I want to use the data result of the first in the second(as shown below). My problem is that I get `undefined` due to the fact that index incremented already inside the second ajax. I want to know how to get the index or valued of the `z` that is not incremented so I can use in the second ajax. The solution I used is to put all the request in the `.done()` of ajax but it didnt solve.

> Any much cleaner solution is welcome.
>
> Any suggestion is appreciated.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'php1.php',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    id: id
  },
  success: function(data) {
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  for (var z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
    var tdata = [];
    console.log(z); //value is 0
    tdata[z] = data[z];

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php2.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        id: tdata[z].id //working
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(z); //value is 1
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(tdata);
      console.log(z); // value is 1 should be 0
      console.log(tdata[z].id); // id undifined because index is more than 1
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'php1.php',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    id: id
  },
  success: function(data) {
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  for (var z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
    var tdata = [];
    console.log(z); //value is 0
    tdata[z] = data[z];

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php2.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        id: tdata[z].id //working
      },
      success: function(tdata) {
        console.log(z); //value is 1
      }
    }).done(function(tdata) {
      console.log(tdata);
      console.log(z); // value is 1 should be 0
      console.log(tdata[z].id); // id undifined because index is more than 1
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: this is not an aswer i dont even know what is the difference

Answer (score 0):

You should use a closure to make a separate ajax request for each value of z
and make sure to convert the returned json to array (data)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'php1.php',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    id: id
  },
  success: function(data) {
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  var tdata = [];
  for (var z = 0; z < data.length; z++) {
    (function(index) {
      console.log(index);
      tdata[index] = data[index];
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php2.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          id: tdata[index].id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(index);
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(tdata);
        console.log(index); // value is 1 should be 0
        console.log(tdata[index].id);
      });
    })(z);
   }
});
```

Comment: value should be 0 i still get the last index or last value of z

Comment: Silly mistake made here,  move:  var tdata = [];  out of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to synchronization, put following code and check.
**async: false,**

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php2.php',
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      data: {
        id: tdata[z].id //working
      },
      success: function(tdata) {
        console.log(z); //value is 1
      }
    })
```

Comment: I would prefer not to set async false